# Node.ByIndexLookup and Where clause throwing exception

Tags: neo4jclient

I am trying to understand as to why the neo4jClient throws an exception, hope someone here could help me better understand whats going on.

first of all the following code works!!

```
            qry = qry.Start(new 
        { 
            city = Node.ByIndexLookup(model.City.IndexName, "Label", data.RegistredAddress.City),
            state = Node.ByIndexLookup(model.State.IndexName, "Label", data.RegistredAddress.State),
            country = Node.ByIndexLookup(model.Country.IndexName, "Label", data.RegistredAddress.Country),
        });
        qry = qry.Match("(city)-[:BELONGS_TO_STATE]->(state)-[:BELONGS_TO_COUNTRY]-(country)").Return<Node<model.City>>("city");
```

but when I replace it with a different construct as below, it throws an exception

```
            qry = qry.Start(new 
        { 
            city = Node.ByIndexLookup(model.City.IndexName, "Label", data.RegistredAddress.City),
        });
        qry = qry.Match("(city)-[:BELONGS_TO_STATE]->(state)-[:BELONGS_TO_COUNTRY]-(country)");
        qry = qry.Where<model.State>(state => state.Label == data.RegistredAddress.State);
        qry = qry.AndWhere<model.Country>(country => country.Label == data.RegistredAddress.Country);
        var finalQry = qry.Return<Node<model.City>>("city");
```

I get an exception at the line where its trying to add a Where clause.

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unhandled node type MemberAccess in MemberExpression: value
```

detail of the stack trace is as follows

> Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherWhereExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f1c4cf3efbf1b05e\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherWhereExpressionVisitor.cs: line 145
>   System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherWhereExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f1c4cf3efbf1b05e\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherWhereExpressionVisitor.cs: line 65
>   System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherWhereExpressionBuilder.BuildText(LambdaExpression expression, Func`2 createParameterCallback) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f1c4cf3efbf1b05e\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherWhereExpressionBuilder.cs: line 15
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery.<>c__DisplayClassd.<Where>b__c(QueryWriter w) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f1c4cf3efbf1b05e\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherFluentQuery`Where.cs: line 11
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery.Mutate(Action`1 callback) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f1c4cf3efbf1b05e\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherFluentQuery.cs: line 40
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery.Where(LambdaExpression expression) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f1c4cf3efbf1b05e\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherFluentQuery`Where.cs: line 10
>   Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery.Where[T1](Expression`1 expression) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f1c4cf3efbf1b05e\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherFluentQuery`Where.cs: line 34

Just curious to know what is the difference here & which of the 2 approach is a preferred way to query for performance reasons when boath works.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: Have you tried doing this for the `Where` clause: `qry = qry.Where((Model model) => model.State.Label == data.RegistredAddress.State);`, where the 'Model' is the type of your Model (and equivalent for the `AndWhere`)

Comment: @ChrisSkardon : I tried the same "qry = qry.Where((model.State state) => state.Label == data.RegistredAddress.State);" but it still fails. BTW model here is  "using model = Repository.Neo4jModel;" so I changed it accordingly

Comment: Just to clarify further, model is a short for namespace "using model = Repository.Neo4jModel;" which is a namespace where the class State is defined.

Comment: This is fixed in 1.0.0.599, thanks to the pull request from @ChrisSkardon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have a solution that will get the code working<s>, but to get it to work as you currently have it you'll need to put in a feature request / bug report at the [Neo4jClient Issues Page](https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issues?status=new&status=open).</s> *[Issue 151](https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/151) has been raised.*

**First, the solution:**

You need to take the `RegisteredAddress` part of your data object and put it into another object, so:

```
var registeredAddress = data.RegisteredAddress;
```

then use that in your query:

```
var qry = qry.Where((model.State state) => state.Label == registeredAddress.State);
```

This will work and give you the results you want / need.

**The reason:**

Neo4jClient takes your lambda expression and parses it internally using an `ExpressionVisitor` based class. This at the moment will only go one deep in terms of looking for 'constant' expressions (i.e. actual values). Because `data.RegisteredAddress.State` is 2 expressions deep, it can't find the constant expression and such can't use it in the query.

**Performance**

I don't know for certain, but I would have thought the latter approach was fastest as traversal in neo4j is lightning fast, and you've only done one index lookup. There's probably not a whole lot in it to be honest...

Comment: I've created an issue on the Neo4jClient issues list (https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/151/accessing-a-nested-property-as-a)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like this should be happening, now it works. BTW one another question I have is which of the 2 approach is better to query for the data in the neo4j if I have to consider performance.

Comment: I've done a pull request which will fix the issue, so we'll see where that goes - in terms of performance I've edited my post!

Comment: This is fixed in 1.0.0.599, thanks to the pull request from @ChrisSkardon.