# Insert 2 large collections with relations in Neo4j database using c#

Tags: c#, neo4j

I'm building app in c# for test nosql databases performace. I'm trying to insert large collection of to models and create relation like one object from first collection with one object with second collection.

These are my models:

```
public class Movie
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Genres { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string OriginalLanguage { get; set; }
    public string ProductionCountry { get; set; }
    public int VotingsNumber { get; set; }
}
public class Actor
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to do that using this code:

```
    var moviesCollection = Movie.CreateMoviesCollectionForNeo4j(collectionEntriesNumber);
    var actorsCollection = Movie.CreateActors(collectionEntriesNumber);

    for (int j = 0; j < collectionEntriesNumber; j++)
    {
        _client.Cypher.Create("(movie:Movie {newMovie})").WithParam("newMovie", moviesCollection[j]).ExecuteWithoutResults();
        _client.Cypher.Create("(actor:Actor {newActor})").WithParam("newActor", actorsCollection[j]).ExecuteWithoutResults();
        _client.Cypher.Match("(movie:Movie)","(actor:Actor)").Where((Movie movie) => movie.Id == moviesCollection[j].Id).AndWhere((Actor actor) => actor.Firstname == actorsCollection[j].Firstname).CreateUnique("actor-[:STARTED_IN]->movie").ExecuteWithoutResults();

    }
```

but I get exception like:
`Unhandled node type MemberAccess in MemberExpression: value(NoSQLTesting.DatabaseHandlers.Neo4j+<>c__DisplayClass0).moviesCollection.get_Item(value(NoSQLTesting.DatabaseHandlers.Neo4j+<>c__DisplayClass2).j).Id`

Can someone explain me what's wrong and how to do it right?
Thanks,
P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111052/node-byindexlookup-and-where-clause-throwing-exception), the following code may work better for you (and may be more performant, too):

```
var moviesCollection = Movie.CreateMoviesCollectionForNeo4j(collectionEntriesNumber);
var actorsCollection = Movie.CreateActors(collectionEntriesNumber);

for (int j = 0; j < collectionEntriesNumber; j++)
{
    var currMovie = moviesCollection[j];
    var currActor = actorsCollection[j];
    _client.Cypher.Create("(movie:Movie {newMovie})").WithParam("newMovie", currMovie).ExecuteWithoutResults();
    _client.Cypher.Create("(actor:Actor {newActor})").WithParam("newActor", currActor).ExecuteWithoutResults();
    _client.Cypher.Match("(movie:Movie)","(actor:Actor)").Where((Movie movie) => movie.Id == currMovie.Id).AndWhere((Actor actor) => actor.Firstname == currActor.Firstname).CreateUnique("actor-[:STARTED_IN]->movie").ExecuteWithoutResults();

}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why, but it's working now. Thanks :)